# Dynamic imports concurrently? No difference in speed

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  console.time("serially");
  const a = await import('express');
  const b = await import('path');
  console.timeEnd("serially");
```

```
Benchmark 1: node src/example.js
  Time (mean ± σ):      74.7 ms ±   6.9 ms    [User: 74.9 ms, System: 10.5 ms]
  Range (min … max):    70.6 ms … 106.2 ms    27 runs
```

Versus:

```
  console.time("concurrently");
  const ab = await Promise.all([import('express'), import('path')]);
  console.timeEnd("concurrently");
```

```
Benchmark 1: node src/example.js
  Time (mean ± σ):      72.9 ms ±   5.8 ms    [User: 73.8 ms, System: 10.3 ms]
  Range (min … max):    70.1 ms … 101.5 ms    28 runs
```

Both give the same time. Why? Shouldn't they load in parallel? Doesn't matter the package. This is using node 19.10

Comment: Did you profile them? Where does the code spend most of its time?

Comment: No I haven't profiled them. Not sure how. Recommendations?

Comment: Surely the reason is that `express` does import `path` itself, so it's going to be sequential. And `path` is a builtin module that's probably already loaded anyway, even before your main module is executed. If you did load two libraries that a) are completely independent b) use ES modules internally c) consist of a lot of small modules so that their `import` performance is filesystem-bound, you should see a difference.

Comment: @Bergi Right, that makes sense. I figured it was something like that.